# React JS TypeError on product but not in development

Tags: reactjs, redux

well I have a bug that I've spent hours googling about but nothing to explain it.
I have code that runs well in react development but when a create a build, I get the

```
TypeError r.find(..) is undefined
```

I have the following code that maps an array in redux store.

```
{menus.map((menu, index) =>
  <tr key={index}>
    <td>{index + 1}</td>
    <td><img src={menu.image} alt="Pic" className="menu_manager_list_pic" /></td>
    <td>{menu.name}</td>
    <td>{menu.description}</td>
    <td>{menu.price}</td>
    <td>{categories.length > 0 ? categories.find(cat => cat.id === menu.category_id).cat_name : ""}</td>
    <td>{subcategories.length > 0 ? subcategories.find(sub => sub.id === menu.subcategory_id).subcat_name : ""}</td>
    <td>
      <button className="btn btn-sm text-success"
        onClick={() => this.onEditMenu(menu)}>
        <i className="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
        </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
)}
```

The code above works magically fine when I just serve page with

```
npm start
```

but when I create a build with `npm run` build and `npm serve -s` I get a blank page with the error above in the console. What could be happening?

Comment: The provided code snippet might not be sufficient to answer your question. Better if you add `webpack` config for development and production to pin point the issue. Problem seems to be with missing `ployfill` in production config file.

Comment: @PrathapReddy Well I did't do any webpack configuration for this React app, I created it with create-react-app and kind of just serves it like that, Could you tell me if there is more that I need to know here.

Comment: Couldn't see any issues with the above code snippet. Give a try with `.filter` instead of `.find` (Not the answer you are expecting though).

Comment: I have tried .filter()[0] but that too is not working. `categories.find` works but `subcategories.find` doesn't. The firefox redux extension shows the data is an array. also this error on occurs on production

Comment: I got where the error was. I am actually using different Backends for dev n production, so the said category was missing in production db